# How could I go about implementing something like the folder tree used in Google Reader?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, rss

I'm building a website where users can create an account and add RSS feeds to their personalized user page. Users can re-arrange their feed order using a web form. But I would prefer it if they could organize their feeds using some kind of ajax folder tree, like Google Reader.

*(In case you aren't familiar with the Google Reader interface, here is a screenshot -- http://goo.gl/TkG6m)

Currently my tables are set up like this...

USERS

user_id | username | email_address | password

FEEDS

feed_id | feed_name | feed_url | feed_order | feed_owner

I wont go into too much detail. But, basically, the value of "feed_owner" corresponds with a particular "user_id". The "feed_order" determines what order the feeds will be displayed on the user page - by default they have no value until a user assigns one (so they're just displayed alphabetically).

I have no idea where to go from here.

I'm not looking for some magic tutorial (although, I'd be thrilled if there is one). I just need some help figuring a plan of attack for implementing this Google Reader-like folder tree user feeds.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want jstree with the dnd plugin. Take a look at http://www.jstree.com/documentation/dnd, especially the reorder only demo at the bottom.

The first step would be to get your feeds showing up in jstree. Just follow the documentation and you should be fine.

To make life easier, consider setting the id of each element to the feed_id.  This makes saving changes easier, as you can get the ID using `$(elem).attr("id")`

To manage the order, you could bind a function to `drag_finish` that grabs the order from the dom and update the database using AJAX.